# I am really confused on how corpseweft works?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

So I'm relatively new to magic and recently went to a local draft. In one of my matches, my opponent played [Corpseweft](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Corpseweft) and activated its ability to exile 3 creatures from their graveyard and summoned a 2/2, 4/4, and 6/6 black Zombie Horror creature token. Which means he has 3 zombie horrors summoned all at one time. My first question is that shouldn't it actually just be a single 6/6 black Zombie Horror creature token? I kept reading over the card and didn't think it was played correctly, but they insisted me that's how it works. Again, I'm new so I didn't want to further doubt a player more experienced than me.

I have searched around the internet for discussions on this card but there was little information I found. From the little information I did stumble upon though, it seemed like a back and forth argument in which I wasn't sure which side was right. Could someone please clarify all this?

Comment: For future reference, when you want to talk about a specific card in your question (or answer), you can link to its gatherer page with `[mtg:card name]`. I already edited that into your question in this case.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You were correct. When your opponent activated Corpseweft's ability and exiled 3 creature cards from their graveyard, they should have put a single 6/6 black Zombie Horror creature token into play. There is nothing in the text of the ability about putting multiple tokens into play.

In the future, if you have a disagreement like this over how a card or rule works, you should always call a judge. Resolving disputes like this is their primary function.

Comment: Unfortunately, many local gaming store events won't actually have a judge at them.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that there should only be one 6/6 Zombie Horror.  Exiling the cards is part of the cost to activate Corpseweft.  So it goes like this:

1. You pay the mana cost and exile the 3 cards.
2. You put a token into play that's power and toughness are equal to 2x the number of exiled cards (3 cards => 6/6).

For it to do what your opponent suggested it would have to be worded something like "1B: Exile any number of creature cards from your graveyard.  For each card exiled this way, put an X/X Zombie Horror creature token into play where X is twice the number of creature cards exiled before the card this turn plus one."

Also note that the ability only says to put a single token into play.  If you wanted multiple tokens, you would have to activate the ability multiple times, including paying the mana cost and exiling cards each time.

Comment: I'm not even sure if that suggested wording works, because I think exiling multiple cards from a graveyard happens simultaneously. Though I'm not sure, so don't quote me on that. The larger point, that the card doesn't work like that and it would take some rather convoluted wording to make it do so, is absolutely valid.